# How to iterate through an entire directory?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to iterate through a directory with around 4000 json files to create one joined json file containing all elements of the json files. When I try to do so, I can get only about half of the json files to be joined. How can I make sure that all json files are iterated through?

```
json_files = [x for x in os.listdir(profile_directory_1) if x.endswith('.json')]
company_profiles_1 = dict()
for json_file in json_files:
    json_file_path = os.path.join('some/path', json_file)
    with open(json_file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        company_profiles_1.update(json.load(f))
```

I expected the len(company_profiles_1) to be more than 4000, since the directory contains more than 4000 json files, but I only got 2161.

Comment: Perhaps you have duplicate keys?

Comment: Another suggestion, you might want to use the `glob` module instead since your path pattern is pretty much fixed.

Comment: @Selcuk The solution would be making `company_profiles_1` a list instead of a dict, right?

Comment: @PedroLobito We can't comment on that without knowing the exact requirements of the OP. Keeping the same keys and merging duplicate values could also be acceptable.

Comment: Oh, I think making company_profiles_1 into a list works. I'll try testing it further.

Comment: @Selcuk As far as I know, I don't have any duplicate keys.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working with multiple json files in a directory, this is how I got it around! I worked with 55000+ json files and it took 298 seconds to go through all of them and create a DataFrame.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import os
import time
import numpy as np 

start_time = time.time()
d = {'date':[],'action':[],'account':[],'flag':[],'day':[],'month':[],'year':[],'reqid':[]}
for files in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\Username\\Documents\\Jsons'):
    x = 'C:\\Users\\Username\\Documents\\Jsons\\'+files
    with open(x, encoding="Latin-1") as w:
        data = json.load(w)
        for i in range(1,len(data['variables']['aer'])):
            d['date'].append(data['variables']['aer'][i]['date'])
            d['action'].append(data['variables']['aer'][i]['action'])
            d['account'].append(data['variables']['aer'][i]['account'])
            d['flag'].append(data['variables']['aer'][i]['flag'])
            d['day'].append(data['variables']['aer'][i]['day'])
            d['month'].append(data['variables']['aer'][i]['month'])
            d['year'].append(data['variables']['aer'][i]['year'])
            d['reqid'].append(data['reqid'])
```

Furthermore you can add `try:`, `except ValueError:` and `except KeyError:` for even better performance.

And if you want to check for the amount of jsons you have been going through, you can certainly create a list that get's filled with files:

```
d = {'date':[],'action':[],'account':[],'flag':[],'day':[],'month':[],'year':[],'reqid':[]}
num_of_jsons = []
for files in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\Username\\Documents\\Jsons'):
    num_or_jsons.append(files)
    x = 'C:\\Users\\Username\\Documents\\Jsons\\'+files
    with open(x, encoding="Latin-1") as w:
        data = json.load(w)
        for i in range(1,len(data['variables']['aer'])):
            d['date'].append(data['variables']['aer'][i]['date'])
            d['action'].append(data['variables']['aer'][i]['action'])
            d['account'].append(data['variables']['aer'][i]['account'])
            d['flag'].append(data['variables']['aer'][i]['flag'])
            d['day'].append(data['variables']['aer'][i]['day'])
            d['month'].append(data['variables']['aer'][i]['month'])
            d['year'].append(data['variables']['aer'][i]['year'])
            d['reqid'].append(data['reqid'])
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I've tried your method and it seems like the amount of jsons I'm going through is correct - the number of files in the directory. But I'm still getting only a half of them after company_profiles.update(data) as shown in my code above.

Comment: Keep in mind update REPLACES the information when the key is shared between both dictionaries and adds it when not. Are you sure it's impossible that json file number 2000 has a key that also exists in json file number 3430 for example?